# Store variable inside array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, variables

I have some PHP on my site which contains the following portion of code:

`'choices' => array ('london' => 'London','paris' => 'Paris',),`

Currently **this list is static - I manually add to it** however I want to **generate the list dynamically**.

I'm using the following code to **create an array dynamically from WordPress** & store in a variable:

```
function locations() {
   query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'post_type' => 'location'));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $locations = "'\'get_the_slug()'\' => '\'get_the_title()'\',";
      endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   $locations_list = "array (".$locations."),";
   return $locations_list; // final variable
}
```

Now, this is where I'm stuck :-)

How do I now assign `$locations_list` to `'choices'`?

I tried `'choices' => $locations_list` but it crashed my site.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What is the `var_dump` output of `$locations_list`?

Comment: I will try that right now :-)

Comment: Yeah, and update it in the question and reply here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... whut?

```
$locations_list = array();
query_posts(...);
while(have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  $locations_list[get_the_slug()] = get_the_title();
}
wp_reset_query();
return $locations_list;
```

I don't know where you read that you could build variables from a string, but... you can't (except `eval`) so just read the [`array`](http://php.net/array) docs and go from there.

Comment: It's a silly noob mistake. Sorry. When I run that code, my `var_dump ($locations_list)` = `array(0) { }`. There's definitely posts in that custom post type, however. Any ideas?

Comment: Try outputting something inside the loop to see if it's iterating?

Comment: I think, in this case, `'choices'` is the associative index of an array; so what he's trying to do is `$array['choices'] => $locations_list;` ... but I could be wrong. I imagine that the code on his site that reads `'choices' => array (...),` is actually more like `array('choices' => array (...), ... );`

Comment: will do - back in 2 - thanks for your patience with me here :)

Comment: I added an `echo 'test';` to the loop and it doesn't spit it out. Hmm.

Comment: What do you get if you add `var_dump(have_posts())` before the loop?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Is there an error log file on your server?

Comment: `query_posts` seems to be killing it :'( I'll need to fix this and get back to you. Really sorry about wasting your time here fellas. Will be back.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:-

```
function locations() {
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'post_type' => 'location'));
$locations = array();
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $locations[get_the_slug()] = get_the_title();
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
return $locations; // final variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this;

```
<?php
function locations() {
    $locations = array();
    query_posts("orderby=date&order=DESC&post_type=location");
    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            $locations[] = get_the_slug() ."#". get_the_title();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    return $locations;
}

// using
$locations = locations();
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    list($slug, $title) =@ explode("#", $location, 2);
    echo $slug, $title;
}
?>
```